# Can't get a token from the Google API

Tags: authentication, windows-8, windows-runtime, google-api, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to exchange my authorization code for a token with the Google OAuth2 API for my Windows 8 app, but I keep getting HTTP 400 errors.

This is how I perform the request (simplified):

```
var url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
var body = "code=4/LEXF1iAVRZvfCfdQg9r1aFqoYDgV&client_id=904019870963.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=[removed]&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&grant_type=authorization_code";

HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(new Uri(url), new StringContent(body));

response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

Visual Studio usually simply gives me a HTTP 400 bad request error, when I try the same thing in Fiddler I also get an HTTP 400 error, but with this as content:

```
21
{
  "error" : "invalid_request"
}
0
```

I read all the documentation about Google OAuth, I searched on Google and StackOverflow for this issue, I tried changing all different sorts of things in my code (UrlEncode, etc.), I used the Google API Playground to see what kind of requests it performs and compared it with my own requests (couldn't find a difference except for the return URL, the auth code and the user-agent). No matter what I do, I just can't get this working, I've been stuck for hours already.

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Perhaps the redirect URI is an issue here. Have you tried a different one? Either way, my guess would be something is going wrong upon redirecting (you should get a 302 at some point, then you'll be redirected to a new URL that causes the 400 here). Check the URI you receive in the 302 that (should) happen before you receive your 400 error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the body content to get the error json you noticed in Fiddler.

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
var response = httpClient.PostAsync(new Uri(url), new StringContent(body)).Result;
var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

content now holds :

```
{
  "error" : "invalid_request"
}
```

You could project the error in an object, by specifing your error type like: response.Content.ReadAsAsync().Result

For the invalid request part, you should play with UrlEncode. I know you say you tried it, but applying it at the right spots really solves your problem.

```
var body = "code="+WebUtility.UrlEncode("4/LEXF1iAVRZvfCfdQg9r1aFqoYDgV")+
           "&redirect_uri="+WebUtility.UrlEncode("https://yoursite...")+
           "&client_id=904019870963.apps.googleusercontent.com" +
           "&scope=" +
           "&client_secret=********" +
           "&grant_type=authorization_code";

HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
var response = httpClient.PostAsync(new Uri(endpoint), 
    new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")).Result;
```

This is the code that works for me. Should work for you also.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's not the answer to my question. I want to get a token from the API.

Comment: Sorry, was trying to help for your first part, to make Fiddler unneeded. I know that wasn't your main problem. Found some code in one of my projects that should help you solve your real problem.

Comment: Awesome, your changes did the trick. I tried encoding different fields with UrlEncode before, but it didn't work then. Maybe I encoded the wrong fields, maybe it was just because I didn't supply the StringContent object with UTF8 encoding and the x-www-form-urlencoded header. Thanks!